# Trying to add a simple google map on my About page with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a simple google map on my About page using React. I get the below error notification in my terminal: Module not found: Can't resolve 'google-maps-react'. I installed google-maps-react so that shouldn't be the problem. Anyone seeing what's wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './About.css'
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

class About extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const mapStyles = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
            };

        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <h1>About this app</h1>

                <div className="containerabout">

                    <section className="locationmap">
                        <h2>Ironhack Amsterdam campus</h2>

                        <Map
                            google={this.props.google}
                            zoom={14}
                            style={mapStyles}
                            initialCenter={{
                                    lat: 52.370962,
                                    lng: 4.883245
                                }}
                        />

                    </section>
                </div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCw1Cu5QmZqsFLWq-D7m12E3Qqjjj13xWY"
  })(About);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems okay.

Can you try reinstalling the package and then restarting webpack. Check if it is still a problem?

```
yarn add google-maps-react
```

or

```
npm install --save google-maps-react
```

Comment: The map now appears for 1 sec and then disappears again. This notification appears: "Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details." Anyone knows how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: It says the API key is wrong. Is there a way to use another API key? I don't want to give my billing information....

Comment: You should use a valid key https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key.

Comment: Also, could you accept this as the correct answer if it has resolved your original issue?